# Unable to repair Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, repair, bootrepair

My laptop (13 years old, I know it is way too old), had a bad battery, which caused the PC to power off without any action from my side (as if I disconnected the power or kept pressing the power button).

When I tried to boot it after the last time this happened, windows was found to be corrupted. Tried to repair, with no joy. Tried also to access CMD from the repair mode, but for some reason, the admin account I'm using is not being detected.

Tried connected the HDD to another laptop I have as a USB device, and run the sfc, didn't work. Last this I did is, I burned the Windows 10 ISO on a USB Flash drive, and then booted with the Flash Drive and ran the windows installer. From there I accessed the repair your PC, and then accessed the CMD. Tried to run the SFC command:

> *`sfc /SCANNOW /OFFWINDIR=E:\Windows /OFFBOOTDIR=E:\`*

But I got *`Windows Resource Protection could not perform the required operation`*

Does anyone know how to get the Windows back running as I don't want to lose my installed apps or my files by any means.

Comment: When I afriend's computer showed such problems, the cause was a defective hard disk. With a 13 year old computer this is very likely. I suggest to (try to) create a full backup of the HDD. If the disk has errors this will probably lead to error messages. I suggest to use a Linux (Live) system and GNU ddrescue.

Comment: If the repair does not work Profile damage, serious OS damage, or hardware issue. Back up, run hardware diagnostics, and then if all appears well, reinstall Windows.

Comment: I ran a quick chkdsk .. found some errors and resolved them. Running now sfc /r and will see the result ..

Comment: I'm keeping the HDD Replace and reimage as a last resort

Comment: You can test the HDD by booting from USB with another OS, e.g., WinRE or Linux. Check the disk, mount it and examine S.M.A.R.T. stats, etc. If you've valued data on the HDD, it's also a good time to make an image. [Written by one occasionally using  a **2008** 32-bit Acer D250... HDD still good, but Windows replaced by Ubuntu for speed. Keep the PC running if it serves a purpose.]